# Why ExecuteScalar takes time for first call?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Below is my program to measure the time taken by ExecuteScalar for multiple iteration.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
    for(int i=0; i <4; i++){
        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

        string sqlCommand = "Insert into TestTable (SNO, Name) values (" + i + ",' " + i + "')";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCommand, connection);
        connection.Open();
        stopWatch.Start();
        var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
        stopWatch.Stop();
        connection.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Time elapsed to insert row " + i + " : " + stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Output:

```
Time elapsed to insert row 0 : 3
Time elapsed to insert row 1 : 1
Time elapsed to insert row 2 : 0
Time elapsed to insert row 3 : 0
```

My question is why it is taking 3 milliseconds for first iteration and for remaining it is lesser than that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [SQL Server connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx) - the first time you have `connection.Open`, it really does have to build a real connection to the server. On subsequent runs, it's probably picking up the same connection again.

Comment: Is that 2 millisecond difference _really_ matters? Maybe because of connection pooling?

Comment: Aside from not quite accurate method of measuring - it can be multiple reasons for this to happen. For example, sql connection being created only in the very first time and other times it is taken from connection pool.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. In my program am measuring only ExecuteScalar part and not the connection establishment.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to Connection Pooling. Once you establish a connection (regardless of if you close it or not), as long as your connection string remains unchanged, the connections are pooled which leads to quicker consecutive executions.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the establishment of the connection which isn't really ended on close but rather returned to a connection pool and reused on the next iteration.

In general, you may also factor in query plan caching and actual data caching from the DBMS, but in this case that wouldn't really apply for INSERT operations (still, the necessary metadata for it might be cold during the first iteration).

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should be using `ExecuteNonQuery()` method instead. Now talking about the time ; first time it has to establish the connection and then execute the query but for the later iteration that's not the case any more.